# Unable to upload files via file_field using watir and chromedriver

Tags: watir, selenium-chromedriver

I am using ChromeDriver 2.25; Watir 6.0.1 and Chrome v.55

I have the following problem :

```
    irb(main):006:0> browser.file_field(:id=>'filesUploader').set ("C:\\files\\test.PNG")
This code has slept for the duration of the default timeout waiting for an Element to be present. If the test is still passing, consider using Element#exists? instead of rescuing
nknownObjectException
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: element located, but timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for true condition on {:id=>"filesUploader", :tag_name=>"input", :type=>"file"}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="fileFormInner">
<input id="uploadFileAjaxData" value="{"d": {"path": "/"}, "f": "uploadFile", "u": 14696528}" name="d" type="hidden"> <input value="uploadFile" name="f" type="hidden">
<input id="filesUploader" name="file" multiple="" onchange="MP.Files.Uploader.uploadOnChange(this);" style="cursor:pointer; font-size: 36px; width: auto;" type="file">
</div>
```

Next I check if this file_field is visible and does it exist :

```
irb(main):007:0>  browser.file_field(:id=>'filesUploader').exist?
=> true

irb(main):008:0>  browser.file_field(:id=>'filesUploader').visible?
=> false
```

This all works fine in Firefox, but doesn't work in Chrome. This file_field is visible in Firefox, but is not visible in Chrome.

Does anyone have some ideas how can I fix this issue?

Comment: I couldn't repro locally.  Is `<input type="file" id="filesUploader">` visible?  Can you edit your question to include the (minimal amount of) HTML that reproduces the issue?

Comment: This is all html related to this file_field 
`<div class="fileFormInner">
<input id="uploadFileAjaxData" value="{"d": {"path": "/"}, "f": "uploadFile", "u": 14696528}" name="d" type="hidden">
<input value="uploadFile" name="f" type="hidden">
<input id="filesUploader" name="file" multiple="" onchange="MP.Files.Uploader.uploadOnChange(this);" style="cursor:pointer; font-size: 36px; width: auto;" type="file">
</div>`

This element(file_field) is visible for Firefox, but is not visible for Chrome(the same script works in FF but is not working in Chrome)

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, but was able to resolve it by following the work around suggested by [louisjohnson-echo360](https://github.com/watir/watir/issues/497#issuecomment-275826513).

The key is to set Watir.relaxed_locate to false before calling set on file_field.

So for your specific problem, the solution would be:

```
Watir.relaxed_locate = false
browser.file_field(:id=>'filesUploader').set ("C:\\files\\test.PNG")
Watir.relaxed_locate = true
```